# Select max value among rows where another value is the same

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry if the topic name seems confusing -- I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it.

I'm stuck with a SELECT statement. I have a DB with 3 tables:

```
Customer (PK cid, name, city, gender); 
Goods (PK gid, name, price, available[bool]); 
Sales (PK sid, FK cid, FK gid, count, discount, sdate)
```

What I have to do is find maximum discount for goods sold in every city.

So, if a select of city and discount looks like this:

```
city               | discount
-------------------+---------
TARDIS             | 0.1
London             |
London             | 0.05
Boeshane Peninsula | 0.15
London             | 0.1
London             | 0.05
```

What I want to get is:

```
city               | MaxDiscount
-------------------+----------
Boeshane Peninsula | 0.15
London             | 0.1
TARDIS             | 0.1
```

And I'm not sure how to group it by city and find a max discount among the results. The closest I've got is `SELECT city, (SELECT max(discount) FROM Sales, Customer GROUP BY city) as MaxDiscount FROM Sales, Customer ORDER BY city;`, but it doesn't work because it tries to insert several rows into one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select city, max(discount) as MaxDiscount 
from customer, sales, goods
where customer.cid = sales.cid
  and goods.gid = sales.gid
group by city
```

Comment: @Andomar LOL! Keeping it simple!

Answer (score 4):

```
select city,max(discount) as MaxDiscount

from Customer cu

inner join Goods Go on cu.cid = Go.gid
inner join Sales  Sa on cu.cid = Sa.sid
where cu.city like 'XYZ%'

group by city,discount
```

Or:

```
select city,max(discount) as MaxDiscount

from Customer cu

inner join Sales  Sa on cu.cid = Sa.sid
where cu.city like 'XYZ%'

group by city,discount
```

Comment: My statement presumed `City` as in the `Sales` table, but it's in the `Customer` table, so you really need a join.